# GET http request method after redirect when using nsurlconnection SynchronousRequest

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Setting NSMutableURLRequest with setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD", as i only want the HEAD information, and using NSURLConnection with sendSynchronousRequest, as i need the thread to block until the info is retrieved, all works well until URL redirect occurs. It appears that synchronousRequest uses a GET request after it encounters a redirect and downloads the content in the background (Not what i want). Need someone to shine some light on this. Either how to do synchronous request of just the HEAD after redirect or how to block NSOperation (where an `NSURLConnection` is used) until NSURLConnection asynchronously fetches the header information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to instantiate an `NSURLConnection` and use it with a delegate. I thought by default redirects did the right thing, but if not, implement `-connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` to ensure the new request is a HEAD.

You can either:

- Implement this on the main thread
- Subclass `NSOperation` to be "concurrent" and run the connection asynchronously there
- Run the runloop until the connection finishes, creating the equivalent of a synchronous connection

Comment: Used asynchronous connection and used a runloop until the connection finishes. It's a pain since setting up synchronous connection is so much nicer and easier.